# Are the Men in Black an international organisation?

Tags: men-in-black

The *Men in Black* organisation operates in America, we establish that for sure.  The films all are based in America also.  What I would like to know is whether there are any boundaries upon the *Men in Black* organisation i.e. are they focused just in America (which I doubt) or do we see evidence somewhere of agents operating outside of America?

Comment: Good question. While I don't remember any evidence of agents operating outside the US, there are plenty examples of large computer screens and maps that show some kind of activity (as in, blinking lights) all over the world.

Comment: Then again, in the very first scene in the first movie, there was an, ahem, illegal alien they could only catch because it crossed the border from Mexico

Comment: @MrLister IIRC the MIB tell aliens living on Earth that they need to stay within a specific area. It seems like they try to spread them over the whole world instead of keeping them all in one place. Likely to avoid calling too much attention to one place. When a city like New York would be overcrowded with aliens, even the MIB could not contain all the rumors. Conspiracy theorists from all around the world would come to NY and start snooping around. And sooner or later they will stumble upon something.

Comment: Aliens need to stay in NYC unless they have a permit from the MIB to move elsewhere. Remember the octopus alien birth scene?

Comment: @MrLister: "they could only catch because it crossed the border from Mexico" - I understand that scene rather in a way that the alien's crossing the MX -> US border gave the MIB the opportunity to pretend they are a part of U.S. border police dealing with illegal immigrants. Had the alien been elsewhere, the MIB would likely have used another cover story for their appearance that would be fitting for the respective situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MIB are indeed international.
From the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Men-in-Black.html):

> (Men in Black headquarters)
>   ON THE MAIN FLOOR, they walk briskly across the room, reaching a giant
>   screen on the far wall.
>
> **KAY:** *Observation, the heart of our little endeavor.*
>
> The screen displays a map of the world on which thousands of tiny lights
>   blink in all parts of the globe, log lines of data flashing next to them.
>
> **KAY:** *This map shows the location of every registered alien on Earth at any given time. Some of them we keep under constant surveillance.*

There is more, like the leather-bound book entitled 
"*Active on Earth*" Jay receives after signing up.

Additionally, in Men In Black II, we saw an agent in Antarctica on the massive screen. The agent states "Zed, the Treaty is Signed", meaning MIB likely has at least some international juristiction.

Comment: Good answer, but could you do some research as to whether there is any evidence of MIB agents outside of America?  If you can't find anything, that's fine - just make a point of saying it!  Cheers ;)

Comment: @N_Soong , there is specific evidence of it, and it has been noted.

Comment: with the new MIB movie literally titled Men in Black: International, it's even more apparent that yes MiB is not just a new york organization